# Accessing Grails TagLib from Service Has Changed in 2.0

Tags: grails, service, taglib

In Grails 1.3.7 I was able to do the following in a service:

```
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
g.eachError(bean: domainInstance) {
   postResponse.errors."${it.field}" = g.message(error: it)
}
```

In 2.0.1 something has changed and now I get a vague exception on the g.eachError line:

```
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
   Line | Method
->>  21 | preparePostResponse in com.wbr.MyService$$ENRVKfei
```

I have no idea what has changed or what is actually causing the null here.  domainInstance is not null.  g is not null.